# Decode Bitmapstream - memory issue

Tags: android, video, jpeg, decode

I read an UDP-Stream which contains a video split into frames.

In order to decode the stream I use the following code:

```
iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[]) msg.obj)));
```

But now I see tons of "GC_FOR_ALLOC freed" memory warnings.

```
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1958K, 42% free 11178K/19060K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1958K, 42% free 11178K/19060K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
```

Is there any way to improve the performance or do this in a better way, without this memory warnings

Comment: Oh sorry :D I pressed "enter" to early

Answer (score 0):

These memory log entries are perfectly normal and occur across all Apps - they are not really warnings, just informational.

Unless your App is actually in danger of getting OutOfMemory exceptions, you are safe to ignore them.

Comment: Is there a better way to convert a ByteArray to an image, because I get an Heap Info Message and the ram is at the limit of 32MB

Comment: Native code doesn't have the Java heap limit and can get better performance, but it complicates your app.